# Passing Oracle Table partition name as parameter in IICS

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

I am trying to pass the partition name as an in-out parameter in IICS.

select * from xyz partition('$$p_partition')

I am getting mostly *[informatica][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended* error. My param file is fine. I tested other parameters without any issues.

How can I pass the parameter successfully?

Comment: To really answer that would require both Informatica knowledge AND Oracle knowledge, as it is parsed at both layers. I can speak only for the Oracle layer. Oracle does NOT want single-quotation marks around the partition name, so make sure Informatica is removing those quotation marks when it replaces $$p_partition. If it isn't, you'll need to remove them. Hopefully Informatica will be good with that. If it isn't, try double-quotes. Double-quotes can be used around object identifiers in Oracle. Single-quotes cannot.

Comment: try without quotes `select * from xyz partition($$p_partition)` ?

Comment: Try without quotes. But first check the session log and verify what is actually being run at Oracle. Copy the statement and verify if it works. This should get you close to understanding the issue and solving it!

Comment: @KoushikRoy : Tried all combination. I am getting the same error. I think i can overcome the issue by parameterizing the entire query itself.

Comment: how does it look like in session log?